# Apk generated with expo does not ask for permissions when it is installed

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, expo

My problem is that my application when I am testing it with a yarn start or expo start asks me for camera permissions and permissions to use other phone credentials such as fingerprint. However, when I generate an apk with expo build: android, when installing it it does not ask for the permissions to the resources, and in the information of the app from the phone it notifies me that the application did not ask for permissions to use any resource.

```
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "Page",
    "slug": "Page",
    "privacy": "public",
    "sdkVersion": "34.0.0",
    "platforms": [
      "ios",
      "android",
      "web"
    ],
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./assets/5_5_R-icon.png",
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/splash1.png",
      "resizeMode": "cover",
      "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
    },
    "updates": {
      "fallbackToCacheTimeout": 0
    },
    "assetBundlePatterns": [
      "**/*"
    ],
    "ios": {
      "supportsTablet": true
    },
    "android":{
      "permissions":["CAMERA_ROLL"],
      "package":"com.ivanzapata.page"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the format in which the app.json was uploaded, The part that really matters is the permissions

Comment: Does your app crashes without asking for the stated permissions? If no, then maybe the permissions has already been granted and in other to be asked again you may need to clear the app's data from settings.

Comment: Directly never ask for permissions. In the information of the app within the phone settings I am informed that my app does not require any permission.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your permissions in app.json need to be the Android permission names, not the expo ones. See https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/permissions/#android-permissions-equivalents-inside-appjson

So your app.json should be

```
    "android":{
      "permissions":["READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE", "WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"],
      "package":"com.ivanzapata.page"
    }
```

Comment: I am also using the phone security credentials as the fingerprint.
What would that permit be?

Comment: The permission I was looking for was USE_FINGERPRINT and the equivalent to BarCodeScanner that insurance must be CAMARA. Thanks for the help!